# Confused about SQL syntax to be used in phpMyAdmin dialect

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using SQL statements embedded in two PHP files to produce a database that appears in HTML as well as in phpMyAdmin. I have created a table like with the following command:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE WeatherCenter (OutgoingLongwaveRadiation VARCHAR(30))";
```

In the second PHP file, I have:

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE WeatherCenter
            ADD COLUMN (
                `Barometric Pressure` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                `CloudType` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
                `WhenLikelyToRain` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);";
```

When I execute the files, I keep getting "Undefined column Barometric Pressure does not exist in filed list". I realized that this is because somewhere else in my PHP file I listed the variable as BarometricPressure and not Barometric Pressure (ie. one has a gap, and the other doesn't). When I corrected the mistake in the ALTER TABLE by deleting the gap, the same error message STILL appeared in the phpMyAdmin database. It seems to me that changing the name of the field in the PHP file does NOT change it in the phpMyAdmin database. As a result, no data is being transmitted to the database.
Could someone tell me if I changed the syntax of the above to

```
 $sql = "ALTER TABLE WeatherCenter
 ADD COLUMN `Barometric Pressure` SMALLINT NOT NULL AFTER `OutgoingLongwaveRaadiation`,
 ADD COLUMN `CloudType` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL AFTER `BarometricPressure`,
 ADD COLUMN `WhenLikelyToRain` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL AFTER `CloudType` ;";
```

will the problem go away? I mean, do you HAVE to use an "ADD COLUMN" before EACH field name, and do you HAVE to specify the "AFTER previous field name"? Do you have to take these additional measures to ensure that any mistake in the field name that appears in the phpMyAdmin can be erased by rewriting your code in the PHP file? Could someone simply tell me what the correct syntax is please, because there appears to be inconsistencies. Some of the ALTER TABLE statements do not have opening and close brackets and no backticks, but other ALTER TABLE statements make it clear that you must have opening and closing brackets and backticks such that the last few characters in the ALTER TABLE statement MUST be );";

I am throughly confused.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a database *client*, not a database.

Comment: In short, to answer your questions: yes, yes, no, no ;-)
Syntax for the `ALTER` command in MySQL (for which PhpMyAdmin is only a client, as Quentin said): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html